# Natting of AWS EC2 public IP and primary private ip

Tags: python, nat

I am trying to set up a simple web service but when I do an HTTP request to the port 8080 of my server nothing happens...
I have discovered that the simple python server that i have set up listens on the 8080 port of the primary private IP and not on the public IP port.

How can I send the HTTP requests to the python script? Do I have to NAT?

I am on ubuntu 14.04 server

This is the simple python web server

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urlparse

class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        parsed_path = urlparse.urlparse(self.path)
        self.wfile.write(parsed_path.query[2:])
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
    server = HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), GetHandler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Did you set up security groups to allow  certain IPs to access port 8080?

Comment: I added Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 0.0.0.0/0, now the browser give me connection refused instead of just waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set a rule for port 8080! Thank you to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
server = HTTPServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), GetHandler)
```

To use the IP address of the public IP network adapter instead of "0.0.0.0"

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your answer! I googled for "public IP network adapter" but i was not able to find which is the IP, do I have to look on amazon service or use some command on my instance via ssh?

Comment: Use the ifconfig command in the instance to list its network adapters? or the ip command - see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-ethernet-adapter-ubuntu-linux/